# How is bridge for beginners taught in Taiwan or Italy today, Precision or another method?

Tags: bridge, bidding, teaching

I play duplicate bridge, and have recently begun studying the Precision bidding system on my own.  Precision was invented by C.C. Wei in the 1960's with Truscott's assistance, and was used with great success by the Taiwanese and Italians at the world championship level during the late 1960s and early 1970s, respectively.

I was wondering how beginning bridge is taught these days in those countries, Taiwan and Italy.  Of course, Standard American and Two-Over-One are the main methods taught in the U.S., and, for example, our Bridge Club has yet to offer Precision Bidding lessons.

I imagine that in Taiwan and Italy Precision is taught in beginning bridge lessons, but I am having a difficult time confirming this on the internet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The canapé-based *Blue Club* systems (both *Roman* and *Neapolitan*) have also always been popular in Italy, so I expect to see that those are taught as well.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I believe in most places, novices are taught the "natural" way. i.e. when you bid a suit, you have length in that suit.

Which means they are probably first introduced to system similar to the standard american.

Comment: Acol, some versions of Neapolitan club, canapé in France are all "natural" systems and all very unlike both Standard American, and each other.

Comment: Precision itself is rightly touted as a "natural system". Shenken's Big Club system (another natural system) originated before the invention of Contract Bridge by Vanderbilt in 1925. Many *canapé* adherents believe that such systems are *more natural* than non-canapé systems.